# CouchApp vs Node.js

Tags: javascript, comparison, node.js, couchdb, couchapp

On the frontend Im using Sproutcore.

The question is how the backend is going to look like.

Solutions:

- CouchApp
- Node.js between Sproutcore and CouchDB

Could CouchApp really replace Node.js on the backend regarding?

- Websockets/streaming
- Asynchronous processing
- Collection of third party libraries
- Security
- Speed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CouchApp is nothing more than an easy way to deploy code to your CouchDB. It doesn't expand it's functionality but let's you use what's given easy way.
So it's not CouchApp vs Node.js but rather what doesn't CouchApp have from the list of features you need to build your app.

If you need websockets/streaming go with Node.js middleware. CouchDB doesn't have 'em.

And if you give some details about your project I can try to give more complete answer.

Comment: Well, CouchDB has _changes which is decent for long-polling. Still, you're right and it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Also worth checking out for couchapps is kan.so for package management a lot like node and easy deployment of couchapps.

Comment: That's interesting. It looks like couchdb ecosystem has grown a lot in the last two years.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you watch Mikeal Rogers talk on how CouchApp and Node.js work together.  http://jsconf.eu/2010/speaker/nodejs_couchdb_crazy_delicious.html

Keep in mind that a couchapp is, at it's very basic level, simply a file structure within Couchdb (_design) where your js (or other) code resides and is served from.  The key benefit is that any code changes in one place will be replicated to all couchdb instances.  It makes it a lot easier to maintain widely distributed code.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So do I believe in my week or two experience with CouchApp.